# How to Display a Toast Widget in A Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am in an activity fragment whereby i want to display a toast widget **after the commands for the submit button have been met** and completed.

the code:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private val currentUserDocRef = Firebase.firestore.collection("users")

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

    view.apply {

        submitbutton.setOnClickListener {
            FirestoreUtil.updateCurrentUser(
                edittextPersonname.text.toString(),
                editTextBio.text.toString(),
                editTextTextEmailAddress.text.toString(),
                edittextage.text.toString()

                )
        }

        return view
    }

}
```

no error is present in my code however on trying to declare a toast widget i get an error. code:

```
 Toast.makeText(this@HomeFragment, "saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

the error:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: What error code do you get?

Comment: @Abhimanyu I have just updated

Comment: Check if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a context to show toast, here is the code :

```
Toast.makeText(this@HomeFragment.requireActivity(), "saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Thanks

Comment: straight to the point answer that solves the issue. thanks

Comment: That doesn't work now

Answer (score 1):

The context should not be nullable type. The error shows that it is a type mismatch.

**Option 1:**

```
Toast.makeText(context!!, "saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

The `!!` (not-null assertion operator) is used to denote the variable is not null.

**Option 2:**

Using let and safe calls

```
context?.let{ context->
    Toast.makeText(context, "saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Refer: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html for more details

Comment: i think its mostly because none of it requires to make a safe call

Comment: kindly, if you dont mind, give my question an upvote